# How do I remove the "border-bottom" from a specific image that links to other websites?

Tags: css

I have an add this button on the website that is rendering a border bottom in the subheader.  This seems to be because the CSS is attributing a border bottom to all hyperlinks in that subheader box.  However, I want to remove the border bottom from the images (twitter, rss) only.  I've tried various methods with no success.  My most recent attempt involved adding custom CSS to the border bottom:
`#subheader   a  {
border-bottom: none;
}`

Here is my website: http://edhaj.tumblr.com/

Thanks for any help on this!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new rule like this one should work:

```
#subheader .addthis_toolbox a {
  border-bottom:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the selector from `#subheader a` to `#subheader > a` does the trick in your case because the links you want to give a border-bottom style are direct child nodes of the div with the id `subheader` but the other linked elements are not.

Answer (score 0):

Well those images are within your addthis box so did you try:

```
#subheader .addthis_toolbox a {border-bottom: 0 none;}
```